# Link table in relationship laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am making an accounting system in Laravel in which I have products, and clients. 
I want to set separate price of each product for each client i.e without setting percentage for each discount. For this I have made a separate table for prices.

My table schema is

```
Products(id,name,category,stock)
Clients(id,name,email,city)
Prices(product_id,price_id,price(String))
```

But I am unable to set Laravel relationship . 
I am making a prices function in product table as

```
public function prices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Client','prices','product_id','client_id');
}
```

and in client table as

```
public function prices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product','prices','client_id','product_id');
}
```

but I am unable to use $product->prices to get prices etc. How can I use this kind of relationship in Laravel ?

Comment: Can you rephrase a bit? Do you want to have a different price for each product varying on the client?

Comment: Also, shouldn't the second column of your `Prices` pivot table be `client_id` instead of `price_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have **many-to-many** relationship between your products and your clients, and you need to work with any additional columns on your pivot table, you need to specify that with the relation definition. So for example in your `Product` model you might have this:

```
public function prices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Client', 'Prices', 'product_id', 'client_id')->withPivot('price');
}
```

The `withPivot` method tells Laravel you need the `price` column to be fetched, in addition to the relation ID columns. To get the prices for a product you can then do the following:

```
foreach($product->prices as $price)
{
   $price->pivot->price; // to get the price for each individual client
}
```

To do this for the `Client` model, you would need the following (specifing again the `price` column as part of the relation):

```
public function prices()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Product', 'Prices','client_id','product_id')->withPivot('price');
}
```

And to get the prices for a client:

```
foreach($client->prices as $price)
{
   $price->pivot->price; // to get the price for each individual product
}
```

You can read more about this in the [Laravel Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables).

Comment: But how will i get a product price of a specific client ?

Comment: Please test this before marking this as the answer to your solution.

Comment: I'll update my answer with a response to your comment.

Comment: Sorry for my dumbness but how will i will i get price of product x for client y ? Above solution gives all prices for a client or product. Will i have to use foreach loop and if statement to check price of each product ? 

Is it possible
foreach($client->prices as $price)
{
   $price->pivot->price->where('product_id','=',1);
}